# IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I am not able to add application into Test Workbench which is built using MFP v8. I am getting an error message while uploading the application into the Test Workbench.

Error message:
: this application is not a supported IBM MobileFirst Platform one. Please consider using IBM Rational Test Workbench

Eclipse version Used: 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Plug-ins:
IBM MobileFirst Foundation Studio 8.0.0
IBM MobileFirst Platform TestWorkbench 8.7

Answer (score 0):

Test Workbench is not supported for MFP 8.0. Hence the message:

"Error message: : this application is not a supported IBM MobileFirst Platform one. Please consider using IBM Rational Test Workbench"

Comment: Is there any other solution?...Why its shows "Please consider using IBM Rational Test Workbench"